# Amchart switch bullet on/off

Tags: javascript, jquery, amcharts

have some graph with bullet displayed:
[image]

my chart is created wit JSON script:

```
var chart2 = AmCharts.makeChart("idchart",.....);
```

How to disable bullets with javascript accessing object chart2?

thank you

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the value of bullet on each graphs.

```
$.each(chart2.graphs, function(key, value){
    value.bullet = 'none';
});
```